# React Native How to pass a list with objects that contains a list to work with FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a FlatList that contains an array with objects that has an array and I can't get it to work.

my error message:

> “Invariant Violation: Object is not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {DATA, MESSAGE, STATUS}). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children use an array instead
>   ”

tho I can get it to work with a normal list like [1,2,3,4]

here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
class FilterScreen extends Component {
state = {
  data: [{"DATA":[{"filter_id":"44","filter_name":"filter 1"},{"filter_id":"45","filter_name":"filter 2"},{"filter_id":"46","filter_name":"filter 3"},{"filter_id":"47","filter_name":"filter 4"},{"filter_id":"48","filter_name":"filter 5"}],"MESSAGE":"DATA FOUND","STATUS":200}],
}
renderRow = ({item}) => {
 return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{item.DATA.filter_name}</Text> // my error points to this line
    </View>
    )
 }
 render() { 
  return (
   <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
     <FlatList 
       data={this.state.data}
       renderItem={this.renderRow} 
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
   </View>
  );
 }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 MainContainer: {
  marginTop:50,
 },

});
export default FilterScreen;
```

I want my FlatList to print out the filter_name, like this

filter 1
filter 2
filter 3
filter 4
filter 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful on how your data is structured. Your `this.state.data` is an array. Inside your array you have two objects. A `DATA` and a `MESSAGE` object.  So if you want to pass the `DATA` object to renderItem, you have to pass `this.state.data[0].DATA`, like here:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList 
       data={this.state.data[0].DATA}
       renderItem={this.renderRow} 
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
 </View>
```

Then you need to adapt your renderItem function to:

```
 //remove the comment inside return, otherwise you will get again an error 
 renderRow = ({item}) => {
 return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{item.filter_name}</Text>
    </View>
    )
```

Working example: 
https://snack.expo.io/BkmD4V12V

Comment: thank you so much for your help, now im getting the same problem but the difference is that im getting my state from a server. My states structure is the same. here's my example: https://snack.expo.io/@thesvarta/tenacious-sandwich?session_id=snack-session-EpJYEZUmN

Comment: @Avoka94 please ask a new question. If you want you can notify me here and i will have a look on it. Thank you!

Comment: here's my new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044935/react-native-how-to-pass-a-list-with-objects-from-server-to-flatlist

Comment: Hey @Tim!, I have a new question, hope you can help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204457/react-native-flatlist-gets-infinity-loop-onrefresh