# How to pass a list with objects from Server to FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a FlatList that contains an array with objects that has an array from a server and I can't get it to work.

my error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read proparty 'Data' of undefined

I can get it to work with my normal list that's not fetched from a Server. Heres the structure from my working list

```
[{"DATA":[{"filter_id":"44","filter_name":"filter 1"}, {"filter_id":"45","filter_name":"filter 2"},{"filter_id":"46","filter_name":"filter 3"},{"filter_id":"47","filter_name":"filter 4"},{"filter_id":"48","filter_name":"filter 5"}],"MESSAGE":"DATA FOUND","STATUS":200}]
```

My server list have the same structure but different values of filter_name and filter_id

here's my code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
    data: [],
    oldData: [{"DATA":[{"filter_id":"44","filter_name":"filter 1"},{"filter_id":"45","filter_name":"filter 2"},{"filter_id":"46","filter_name":"filter 3"},{"filter_id":"47","filter_name":"filter 4"},{"filter_id":"48","filter_name":"filter 5"}],"MESSAGE":"DATA FOUND","STATUS":200}],
    page:1,
    status: null,
    isLoading: false,
    }
}
getData = async () => {
const url = 'api/getFilter.php?page='+this.state.page+'&row_per_page=5';
fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
   this.setState({
    data:this.state.data.concat(responseJson),
    isLoading:false
   });
})
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}
renderRow = ({item}) => {
  console.log('item', item);
  return (
   <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text>{item.filter_name}</Text>
   </View>
  )
}
render() {
   console.log('state', this.state.data[0]);
   console.log('oldstate', this.state.oldData[0]) // this 
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList 
      data={this.state.data[0].DATA}
      renderItem={this.renderRow} 
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
     </View>
  );
}
```

Expo: https://snack.expo.io/@thesvarta/tenacious-sandwich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that on the initial rendering of your component `this.state.data` is empty, because we have to wait until `getData` returns any data. That's why you cannot access `this.state.data[0].DATA` at the beginning.

The solution is to update your `getData` function a little bit.

```
getData = async () => {
    const url = 'http://ollenorstrom.se/ollenorstrom.se/avoka/api/getFilter.php?page='+this.state.page+'&row_per_page=5';
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      // here we save the data, we want to access later. 
      console.log('responseJson', responseJson[0].DATA);
       this.setState({
        data:this.state.data.concat(responseJson[0].DATA),
        isLoading:false
       });
    })
  }
```

Now your data is directly stored in `this.state.data`. We now can simplify your `render()` function:

```
 <FlatList 
       data={this.state.data} // simplified, passing an empty array at the beginning is ok
       renderItem={this.renderRow} 
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
```

Working example:

https://snack.expo.io/HJ--GFlnN